# Optimize search method with MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, full-text-search, preg-match-all

I created a search engine that takes too much time to return the results.
So I ask you if  there is a faster and easier method to get the same results?

I would like that if I search for two specific terms, the database returns only results that contains only these terms and no more.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

if($_GET['s']) { //es. banana,orange yellow

    //put separeted words into an array
    preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z]{3,})/', $_GET['s'], $s);

    $a = array();
    $b = array();
    $c = array();

    foreach($s[0] as $val) {
        echo '<mark>'.trim($val).'</mark>,';
        array_push($a,"terzoCampo LIKE '%".trim($val)."%'");
    }

    $lk = implode(' AND ',$a);

    $q = " SELECT * FROM nomeTabella WHERE $lk ORDER BY primoCampo ";

    $r = $db->query($q);

    if($r->num_rows >0)
    {

        while($v = $r->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z]{3,})/', $v['terzoCampo'], $x);
            if(count($s[0])==count($x[0]))
            array_push($b,$v['primoCampo']);
        }

    }

    $r->close();

    if(count($b)>0) {

        echo '<h2>'.count($b).' risultati trovati</h2>';
        $b = implode(',',$b);

        $q = " SELECT * FROM nomeTabella WHERE primoCampo IN ($b) ORDER BY primoCampo ";

        $r = $db->query($q);

        if($r->num_rows >0)
        {

            while($v = $r->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                echo '<li><strong>'.$v['secondoCampo'].'</strong> <em>'.$v['terzoCampo'].'</em> </li>';
                array_push($c,$v['primoCampo']);

            }

        }

        $r->close();

        $c = implode(',',$c);
        $ex = "AND primoCampo NOT IN ($c)";

    }

    else 
    $ex = '';

    echo '<h3>Ricette correlate</h3>';

    foreach($s[0] as $val) {

        $q = " SELECT * FROM nomeTabella WHERE terzoCampo LIKE '%".trim($val)."%' $ex ORDER BY primoCampo ";

        $r = $db->query($q);

        if($r->num_rows >0)
        {
            echo '<h4>'.trim($val).' ('.$r->num_rows.')</h4>';

            while($v = $r->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                echo '<li><strong>'.$v['secondoCampo'].'</strong> <em>'.$v['terzoCampo'].'</em> </li>';
            }
        }

        $r->close();

    }


}

?>
```

Comment: Using `% X %` in a search is slow almost by definition, because such a search cannot benefit from indexes. That's why most search functionalities usually support only exact matches or 'starting with'. The fact that you used `SELECT *` is also a concern. Not slow per se, but it is bad practice to select just every field instead of looking closely to what exactly you need to fetch. Instead of using `LIKE` you may have a look at [`FULLTEXT` indexes and the accompanying `MATCH..AGAINST` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: I am guessing that you are storing attributes as a delimited list.  If so, this is wrong, and you should fix your data structure to get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing text search . You must apply the FULL TEXT INDEX for matching criteria.

Example:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX index_name ON tbl_name (title,content);
```